# Why am I unable to see my website on the Hybris Smartedit Portal?

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

I followed the steps on the Hybris wiki and added the following extensions to my localextensions.config:

```
<!-- Smart Edit -->
<extension name="cmssmartedit"/>
<extension name="cmssmarteditwebservices"/>
<extension name="cmswebservices"/>
<extension name="permissionswebservices"/>
<extension name="previewwebservices"/>
<extension name="smarteditaddon"/>
<extension name="smarteditwebservices" />
```

I installed the smarteditaddon to my custom storefront. When I sign in to my smartedit all I see is "Your Site" but I am not shown any websites nor even an option to select one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update under platform > update in the hybrid administration console by ticking the relevant extensions and then selecting update